# AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" whit Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm trying to understand how to scrape website pages with java content. I'm stuck with selenium and I think I've some problem in understanding the mechanism.
I've got this script:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class britaudioSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "britaudio"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["www.example.com/archive-project"]

    def __init__(self):
        caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        caps["marionette"] = True
        caps["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox"

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        el1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="level1"]/li[@class]/href')
        el1.click()
        el2 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//id[@class="subNavContainer loaded"/ul[@class="level2"]/li[@class]/href')
        el2.click()
        el3 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//id[@class="subNavContainer loaded"/ul[@class="level3"]/li[@class="track"]/href')
        print el3
```

This gives me this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 62, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
exceptions.OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f050dd751d0>> ignored
```

I actually don't understand how web.driver works. Somebody can help?

I've already seen this question: [Python Selenium Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in selenium.webdriver.ie.service.Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004635/python-selenium-exception-attributeerror-service-object-has-no-attribute-pr), but it doesn't seem it can be applied to my case.

Comment: What is the output of `which firefox`?

Comment: Does it work if you ignore the capabilities?

Comment: Nope, if I use just driver = webdriver.Firefox() it doesn't.

Comment: What's your firefox version?

Comment: The firefox version is 4.7. I know that there are problems with that, that's why I followed those instructions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver